# How to prove that if $E[X^2]$ is finite then $n\Pr[\lvert X\rvert>\varepsilon\sqrt n]\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0$?

Tags: probability-theory, inequality, convergence-divergence

Let $X$ be a random variable with $E[X^2]<\infty$. I want to prove that
$$ n\Pr[\lvert X\rvert>\varepsilon\sqrt n]\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0 \text. $$

I tried to apply Chebyshev's inequality, but it only yields
$$ n\Pr[\lvert X\rvert>\varepsilon\sqrt n] \leq n\frac{E[X^2]}{n\varepsilon^2} = \frac{E[X^2]}{\varepsilon^2} \text. $$
At least that bound doesn't *diverge*, but on the other hand it doesn't imply anything useful either. Chebyshev's inequality with higher powers $p$ of $X$ would help, but then $E[\lvert X\rvert^p]$ might be infinite.

How does one approach this problem?

Comment: Since Chebyshev's inequality is in general tight, you will need to argue that you can't have *one* r.v. that makes it tight for all $n$. That may not be simple; I could see a situation where your distribution looks like an infinite sum of dilations of the distribution described at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality#Sharpness_of_bounds

Comment: Another idea: consider for a moment r.v.s with pdf proportional to $x^{-3-\delta}$ on $[1,\infty)$ and zero elsewhere, where $\delta>0$. Then your quantity, in terms of $n$, behaves like $n^{-\delta/2}$ as $n \to \infty$. So it does decay, but slower and slower as $\delta$ goes to zero. (On the other hand, the variance also blows up as $\delta$ goes to zero.) One can sum these pdfs with appropriate weights to obtain a pdf which only has a second moment and no higher moments. Could this break your result?

Comment: (Complete) hint: Apply Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem to the random variables $$X_n=n\,\mathbf 1_{|X|>\epsilon\sqrt{n}}\leqslant\epsilon^{-2}X^2.$$

Comment: @Did Very nice. Thank you! If you post this as an answer, I shall accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\infty>E(X^2)/\epsilon^2=E((X/\epsilon)^2)=\int_0^\infty P((X/\epsilon)^2>x)dx$, so comparing the sum to the integral, $\sum_1^\infty P((X/\epsilon)^2>n)=\sum_1^\infty P(|X|>\sqrt{n}\epsilon)$ is also finite, so $ P(|X|>\sqrt{n}\epsilon)=o(1/n)$.

Comment: There is something nontrivial going on in this proof: you are asserting that if $a_n$ is a nonincreasing sequence of nonnegative numbers and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n<\infty$ then $a_n=o(1/n)$. This does not hold without the nonincreasing assumption; I can take $a_n=b_n c_n$ where $b_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ and $c_n$ is an appropriately chosen sequence of zeros and ones. (I think it would be enough to have $c_n=1$ iff $n$ is a perfect square, but the details are not important here.)

Comment: (Cont.) Of course, the nonincreasing property does apply in this context, but that doesn't mean that the statement I gave above is entirely obvious. So I think you need to say more about this part of the problem.

Comment: Correction to my first comment: it's enough to have $c_n=1$ iff $n$ is a perfect cube. With a perfect square we essentially have the harmonic series with a bunch of zeros splashed in between the numbers for no particular reason.